# How to check every single character of a command line argument? Caesar PSET2

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I need to check if inside the command line argument there is a non digit character. For example: ./problem 20x should print out "Not a digit" since it contains an x. My code doesn't seem to loop through all the characters in the command line argument.

I've basically tried different kinds of loops but don't seem to be working.

```
string s = argv[1];

for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
{
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit (s[i]) == false)
        {
            printf(" Not a digit\n");
            return 1; 
        }
    }
    int k = atoi(s);
    printf("Success\n");
    return 1;
    }
}
```

I expect the output of "20x" to print out "Not a digit". Also the output of "x20" should be "Not a Digit"

Comment: Your while loop doesn't increment `i` — you probably should remove the loop control altogether (but keep the `if` that is its body).  The `int k = atoi(s);` and following two lines should be outside the `for` loop.  It is more conventional to use either `if (isdigit(s[i]))` or `if (!isdigit(s[i]))`, if only because `isdigit()` is only guaranteed to return 0 or non-0 so testing for true would be a bad idea (and you don't do it in this code).

Comment: The inner while loop is an infinite loop in the case `s[i]` is a digit.

Comment: Why do you have two loops?

Comment: You can simply declare `int i = 0;`, remove the `for` loop completely, and just loop `while (s[i] != '\0') { if (isdigit (s[i]) == false) { printf(" Not a digit\n"); return 1; } i++; }`. At the end of your code you would generally want `return 0;` as an indication of success instead of `return 1;`. Nit, you can simply use `puts ("Success");` as there are no conversions for `printf` to handle. (a good compiler will optimize this for you). As you go forward, use `strtol` instead of `atoi` as `atoi` provides zero error checking for you to validate the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two for loops for this problem. Either loop will work on its own, and the difference is going to be in the stop condition. I'm going to use a `for` loop in this example, but an analogous implementation using a `while` loop would simply check for the next character being the nul terminator.

```
enum bool_t {
    FALSE,
    TRUE
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No input(s).\n");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (*++argv) {
        int found_invalid_character = FALSE;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(*argv); ++i) {
            if (!isdigit((*argv)[i])) {
                found_invalid_character = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found_invalid_character) {
            printf("%s is not a valid integer.\n", *argv);
            continue;
        }

        int n = atoi(*argv);
        printf("%d is a valid integer.\n", n);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
x20 is not a valid integer.
20x is not a valid integer.
20 is a valid integer.
```

Remember that `argv` is an array of pointers to null-terminated arrays of characters, so you're always going to be able to iterate over a "string" by checking whether you've hit a nul terminator. You could reimplement the functions in `string.h` from scratch if you wanted to by using that for pretty much everything. Here is the `strlen` function for example.

```
size_t my_strlen(const char* s) {
    size_t len = 0;

    while (*s++)
        ++len;

    return len;
}
```

Everytime the `while` condition is evaluated, the `s` pointer is increased and dereferenced. Every value of `*s` is going to be some ASCII value, and therefore non-zero, until the nul terminator is found, at which point the `++len` statement will not be executed. This is why `strlen` conventionally returns the length of the string *minus the nul terminator*.

So basically the `for` loop I used in my example for your program which depended on the string length of the input indirectly depended on finding the nul terminator of the input string. This is why you could just as well use a `while` loop while checking for a nul terminator.

---

As an aside, I did notice that you return 1 at the end of both your success and fail branches, which I was a little puzzled by. Returning 1 conventionally indicates an error, and in fact `stdlib.h` defines the `EXIT_FAILURE` macro as 1. I do use those macros myself, although if you notice I defined `TRUE` and `FALSE` using an enum, which makes them lexically visible to the program as both "FALSE" and "TRUE" as well as 0 and 1, which are their respective values, rather than simply being text-replaced to 0 and 1 by the preprocessor.

Also, you didn't include your headers or previous definitions, but I'm guessing you're on Windows, because `false` isn't a valid value in C without being manually defined, whereas Visual Studio, being a C++ compiler, does allow it. I bring this up because I was confused by the line `string s = argv[1]`. This could mean that you're on a C++ compiler and used the infamous `using namespace std;`, or you typedef'd: `typedef const char* string`. I don't like either option personally, but to each his own.

Anyways, I hope this helps, good luck.